# Turkish characters are not displayed correctly

Tags: php, html, mysql, encoding

MySql database uses utf-8 encoding and data are stored correctly.I use set_name utf8 query to make sure the data called are utf-8 encoded.all variables from database works fine as long as the header charset is utf-8,but the static html characters do not work properly.When i set header charset to ISO-8859-9 variables are displayed differenly while html characters work ok.can anyone help me? 
Utf8 encoding:  http://oi48.tinypic.com/289kje1.jpg   html tags have problem displaying values.but php data(green ones e.g. ağişler) that come from database is ok.ISO encoding http://oi50.tinypic.com/287n2ph.jpg this time the html is ok but php data are displayed wrong.

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-9');
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head><title>noname</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: So, is your content UTF-8 or ISO encoded? It can't be both. Save your source code in UTF-8!

Comment: i want it to be utf-8 encoded but turkish characters do not show up good in utf-8. for example Ş and İ are �� like that when don't include header charset ISO.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try explicitly adding content type at the top of your file as below

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

and remove the below from your code..

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-9');
```

**Update:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo "for example Ş and İ "; ?>   
</body>
</html>
```

The above code gives me the below output:

[image]

Comment: then the static characters are displayed wrong

Comment: show us how are they getting displayed and how would you like them to be with some example or screenshot..

Comment: Utf8 encoding:  http://oi48.tinypic.com/289kje1.jpg   html tags have problem displaying values.but php data(green ones e.g. ağişler) that come from database is ok.ISO encoding http://oi50.tinypic.com/287n2ph.jpg this time the html is ok but php data are displayed wrong.

Comment: please find the update to my reply..and check if it solves the issue..

Comment: well i made it work.the problem was solved after i used utf8-without bom option in my editor.and yours is the answer.thanks

Answer (score 1):

So data from the database works if you tell the browser to interpret it as UTF-8, that means that data is UTF-8 encoded. The HTML code works if you tell the browser to interpret it as ISO-8859, that means the HTML is encoded in ISO-8859.

So you have a document with *mixed encodings*. Bring those two together. Save your source code files as UTF-8 and tell the browser to interpret it as UTF-8, or get your data from the database in ISO-8859 and tell the browser to interpret it thusly.

Comment: yes thats the problem but i'm using eclipse and i don't know how to change the encoding of the source code.

Comment: Look in the help file. Google. That can't be an unsurmountable problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=change+encoding+of+file+in+eclipse