# php encoding of posted data changed

Tags: php, utf-8

I post data from client to php, here is how my post data seems in client:
[image]

I click add and post this string to php with ajax call here how posted data seem in ajax parameter;

```
//username ="Uğur Akkaynak" so its ok. 

    var params = {
        action: "saveAdObjects",
        username_: username,
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../Controller/ActiveDirectoryController.php5",
        type: "POST",
        async:false,
        dataType: "json",
        data: params,
        success: function (result)...
```

In php file I check the posted variable:

```
var user = $_POST["username"]; //UÄŸur Akkaynak wtf!
```

so problem is clear, strings broken in php, I know I need change encoding in php file and tried these:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8'); 
utf8_encode($_POST["username"]);// UÃ„ÂŸur Akkaynak 
mb_convert_encoding ($_POST["username"],'utf-8'); // UÄŸur Akkaynak
```

What should I do get $_POST["username"] as 'Uğur Akkaynak' like posted from client

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517189/turkish-characters-are-not-displayed-correctly

Comment: Where/how/when exactly are you seeing "UÄŸur"? Most likely there's **nothing wrong** here at all, only your method of displaying the string is messed up.

Comment: What is the encoding of the HTML page? It should match the encoding you're using in PHP. You could try echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to add the header:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```

To encode strings on the client side, you could add the following in the `ajax` function:
`contentType:"application/x-javascript; charset:UTF-8"`

```
$.ajax({
        url: "../../Controller/ActiveDirectoryController.php5",
        type: "POST",
        async:false,
        dataType: "json",
        data: params,
        contentType:"application/x-javascript; charset:UTF-8"
        success: function (result)...
```

Also verify that your HTML-head contains:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all you need to observe your request via developer console.

Find about network request and see the parameter value.

if it not correct try add

```
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
```

into your ajax request.