# How can I make substr work with utf-8?

Tags: php, utf-8

Why is my text not displayed properly when I use "substr"?

```
function limitstring($input,$number) {
    if (strlen($input) > $number){
        $input = substr($input, 0, $number) . '...';
    } 
    return $input;
}
```

Input:

```
echo $row['text'];
```

Output: Käse

Input:

```
limitstring($row['text'],60);
```

Output:
  K�se...

Comment: Do you mean `substr()` ? Otherwise, if `limitstring()` is a function you've rolled you'll need to show what that's actually doing.

Comment: @CD001 Sorry, forgot the function. Will post it in a second

Comment: i don't know limitstring php function, but if you are displaying in a html page, try adding `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> <meta charset="utf-8">` in the head

Comment: I think this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517189/turkish-characters-are-not-displayed-correctly Good luck

Comment: @Kaddath Yes, this helped!

Comment: *"How can I make substr work with utf-8?"* -- spell "substr" as: [`mb_substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use multibyte set of functions mb_ when dealing with unicode strings. Check here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php

Answer (score 0):

If you can't switch to [mb_strlen()](http://php.net/mb_strlen) and [mb_substr()](http://php.net/mb_substr) for whatever the reason, which would be the right fix, you need to enable the [mbstring.func_overload](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.configuration.php#ini.mbstring.func-overload) configuration directive. Also, not all regular byte-based string functions have multi-byte equivalents.

Please note that this is mostly a hack and the directive is deprecated in PHP/7.2.0.

Comment: mbstring.func_overload is not recommended as it can (and often does!) lead to more problems than it solves, especially if you have scripts that have to work with data in more than one character encoding.  It is also deprecated and scheduled for removal in the near future

Comment: @GordonM Certainly, and that's what I try to express in my answer.