# I have a Turkish character problem when I use innerHTML in js

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

This is the result when I enter a Turkish character in span with innerHTML.The result is like this, "�r�n Favorilere Eklendi"

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="Main.AddRemoveFavorite(this)" id="true" data-favoriteid="@Model.product.FavoriteId">
<i id="icon" style="font-size:1.2rem; color:#798499;" class="icon-star"></i>
<span id="text" style="font-size:1rem; font-weight:400; color:#798499;cursor:pointer;">Ürünü Favorilerime Ekle</span>
</a>
```

```
document.getElementById("icon").className = "icon-star_alt"
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = 'Ürün Favorilere Eklendi';
$(btn).data('favoriteid', data)
```

Comment: Try adding `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the `<head>` of the HTML document.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Turkish characters are not displayed correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13517189/turkish-characters-are-not-displayed-correctly).

Comment: <meta charset="utf-8"> already exists

Comment: Are you hosting this on a website hosting provider?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using `meta` tag inside your `head`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

You can also check that HTTP server headers are there, because if they are present then the meta tag is ignored by browsers

the header:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> already exists

Comment: The meta tag is ignored by browsers if the HTTP header is present.

Comment: Could it be because of something else?

Comment: have you checked the `http` server header which in mentioned in my answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by converting the file to utf-8.